# ordered grouping of rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I would like to create a new column that sequentially labels groups of rows. Original data:

```
> dt = data.table(index=(1:10), group = c("apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","apple"))
> dt
    index  group
 1:     1  apple
 2:     2  apple
 3:     3 orange
 4:     4 orange
 5:     5 orange
 6:     6 orange
 7:     7  apple
 8:     8  apple
 9:     9 orange
10:    10  apple
```

Desired output:

```
    index  group id
 1:     1  apple  1
 2:     2  apple  1
 3:     3 orange  1
 4:     4 orange  1
 5:     5 orange  1
 6:     6 orange  1
 7:     7  apple  2
 8:     8  apple  2
 9:     9 orange  2
10:    10  apple  3
```

`dplyr` attempt:

```
dt %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate( id= row_number())
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
   index group     id
   <int> <chr>  <int>
 1     1 apple      1
 2     2 apple      2
 3     3 orange     1
 4     4 orange     2
 5     5 orange     3
 6     6 orange     4
 7     7 apple      3
 8     8 apple      4
 9     9 orange     5
10    10 apple      5
```

How can I edit this to get the first group of apples as 1, then the first group of oranges as 1, then the second group of apples as 2 etc (see desired output above). Also open to `data.table` solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
dt[, id := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index) > 1)), by="group"]
dt
#     index  group id
#  1:     1  apple  1
#  2:     2  apple  1
#  3:     3 orange  1
#  4:     4 orange  1
#  5:     5 orange  1
#  6:     6 orange  1
#  7:     7  apple  2
#  8:     8  apple  2
#  9:     9 orange  2
# 10:    10  apple  3
```

---

Starting from original `dt`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index) > 1))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    index group     id
#    <int> <chr>  <int>
#  1     1 apple      1
#  2     2 apple      1
#  3     3 orange     1
#  4     4 orange     1
#  5     5 orange     1
#  6     6 orange     1
#  7     7 apple      2
#  8     8 apple      2
#  9     9 orange     2
# 10    10 apple      3
```

---

Base R, perhaps a little clunky:

```r
out <- do.call(rbind, by(dt, dt$group,
                         function(x) transform(x, id = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index) > 1)))))
out[order(out$index),]
#          index  group id
# apple.1      1  apple  1
# apple.2      2  apple  1
# orange.3     3 orange  1
# orange.4     4 orange  1
# orange.5     5 orange  1
# orange.6     6 orange  1
# apple.7      7  apple  2
# apple.8      8  apple  2
# orange.9     9 orange  2
# apple.10    10  apple  3
```

The names can be removed easily with `rownames(out) <- NULL`. The `order` part isn't necessary, but I wanted to present it in the same order as the other solutions, and `do.call`/`by` does not preserve the original order.

Comment: @r2evans Nice one. I guess you can simplify a bit using `id = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index) > 1))`.

Comment: Yup, sure can ... that's the product of rapid-fire quick-code get-back-to-work. (Thanks, @Shree!)

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `data.table::rleid` twice:

```
dt[, gid := rleid(group)][, id := rleid(gid), .(group)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `rle` from `base R`

```
with(dt, with(rle(group), rep(ave(seq_along(values),
            values, FUN = seq_along), lengths)))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```